# Compatible Data Type

Tags: android, kotlin, types

### I don't know if this issue already exists or not, I didn't find anything. By the way, I've got a problem with the data type.

For example, I've several data from server and these types are Int. So my Model should be Int too to receive the data from the server. Now if the server changes data type to Flot, My app will have a problem. so I should change the data type to Flot too and release a new version of the app. but here, my previous app versions won't work correctly. how can I handle it, if a data type changed from the server, my app work perfectly and get those data?

Comment: a `Number` type will allow both `Float` and `Integer`

Comment: @AbhinavChauhan I know. that was just an example. how to handle it if data type change to String/ Int/ Flot or anything else from the server? I want my app to keep work, handle and show those data

Comment: ok it depends what are you doing with that data, for example if the data is `String` then you're not multiplying , and if it is int then you can, but you can , so there should be something that can be done with all data types, for example calling `toString()`, but why would you be supplied any arbitrary type , i didn't get it

Comment: @AbhinavChauhan I want to know, do we have Data Type Conversion in android? Because in PHP we have, it doesn't matter what data type we will receive, logic will handle it. In the future, if Data type change from String to Int, or Boolean, nothing wrong happen. Can we do something like that in Android too?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It's not a good idea to change the data types from the server side.

But if you have to deal with it, one possible way is to declare the type of your variables as `Any` (the super type of all classes in Kotlin) and when using it, check the type of the variable via `when`, so you can benefit the smart cast too:

```
data class Person (val name: Any)

// Gathering data from the webservice and make an object of the Person class named person

when(person.name){
     is String -> {} // the name variable will be casted to String automatically
     is Float, is Double -> {}
     ..
     }
```

Comment: If we consider data typing Any, isn't there a problem with resources? Does the App take a lot of Ram?

Comment: @A.R.B.N data-type has nothing to do with memory. It just holds the reference to object in memory.

Comment: @A.R.B.N No its just a generalization. Consider the inheritance. Any is the parent of all other objects. so no differences.

Comment: @AnimeshSahu No it is ',' in the Kotlin lang.

Comment: @PouyaHeydari and final question. Is it good practice to set Any to data Type?

Comment: @A.R.B.N it really depends on your purpose of handling the data. Types in statically-typed languages are simply to make compiler aware of thereby making sure operations on them are safe.

Comment: @A.R.B.N As I mentioned in the answer, try avoiding doing something like that. The best practice is to have a stable response that doesnt get changed on the air. as you see, if you can not trust the backend side, you have to write lots of code like this to prevent any problems. and I'd say its a problem itself ;)

Comment: @AnimeshSahu & PouyaHeydari. Thanks, both of you :-)